# Jms runtime selector not working with artemis (for Topic)

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, jms, activemq-artemis, camel-jms

I am using Stringboot, springboot starter artemis and camel

here is my dependencies for them:

```
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-artemis')

compile 'org.springframework:spring-jms'
compile 'org.apache.activemq:artemis-jms-client:1.5.6'
compile 'org.apache.activemq:artemis-jms-server:1.5.6'
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.camel/camel-jms
compile group: 'org.apache.camel', name: 'camel-jms', version: '2.20.2'
```

Here is my code(I am not using jms template here due to some reason)

```
  Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();

            try {
                connection.setClientID(clientId);
                connection.start();

                //Create a JMS session
                Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);

                Topic topic = ActiveMQJMSClient.createTopic(processedHeaders.get(jmsdestination));
******JmsMessageUUID will dynamic, i have added JmsMessageUUID value = ID:142536687 as a example*********
                String selector = "JmsMessageUUID = 'ID:142536687'";
                //Create the subscription and the subscriber.
                MessageConsumer subscriber = session.createConsumer(topic,selector);

                //Consume the message from the durable subscription
                TextMessage messageReceived = (TextMessage) subscriber.receive();
                System.out.println("Received message: " + messageReceived.getText());
                // Acknowledge message
                messageReceived.acknowledge();
            }  finally {
                if (connection != null) {
                    // Close our JMS resources!
                    connection.close();
                } }
        }
```

i am trying to select message with JmsMessageUUID, it is basically a random string which is set during  send message, Jms selector is unable to find out message, but when **i am not using selector** than successfully consumed message also I have checked the jms properties in received message, and the  JmsMessageUUID is available in the properties with same  string value.

I am unable to figure out why **selector** is not working ? Please help me here ..

I have also found **JMSMessageID** filter worked with **Queue** but not with Topoc:(

Comment: Just to make sure: the message is sent **after** you start your Consumer, right? Because a **durable subscriber receives only messages that were sent after he subscribed**.

Comment: Yes but as i have mentioned static selector is part for subscription and so  subscription will only receive filter messages based on  selector, Here i need to configure dynamic selector, I have subscribe  topic  before message sent, but as i mentioned problem is dynamic selector